# Laravel Sanctum unauthenticated with Windows host file

Tags: windows, laravel-sanctum, laravel-10

I have a Ubuntu server on my netwerk where I host Laravel projects. The IP-addresses are stored in my Windows host file (c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts) and set to domains like http://project.test.

When I use Sanctum in a project with these options in my .env, I can't login:

```
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=project.test:8000
SESSION_DOMAIN=.project.test
```

But when I change it to the IP-address and use the same IP in the browser it works:

```
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=172.16.0.20:8000
SESSION_DOMAIN=172.16.0.20
```

How come? Is it possible to use it with my local Windows host file?

I'm using:

- Laravel 10.10
- PHP 8.1
- Windows 11
- Sanctum 3.2.5

My host file:

```
172.16.0.20 project.test
```